# Regular expression to search for text using star characters

Tags: java, regex, search, filter

I'm writing a Java application where a user can reduce a List of strings based on a filter that the user supplies.

So for example, the user could enter a filter such as:

```
 ABC*xyz
```

This means that user is looking for strings that start with ABC and have xyz that follow (That would be the same as doing a search for `ABC*xyz*`)

Another example of a filter the user could enter is:

```
 *DEF*mno*rst
```

This means that the string can start with anything, but it must then follow with DEF, followed by mno, followed by rst.

How would I write the Java code to be able generate the regular expression that I need to figure out if my strings match the filter the user has specified?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0515.html

Comment: `*` is transformed to `.*` (`ABC*xyz` -> `ABC.*xyz`) so what's a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If converting your syntax to regex, which is the "easy" way to do this (avoiding writing a lexer yourself), you *must* remember to escape your string appropriately.

So if going down this route, you should probably aim to quote the bits that *aren't* wildcards in your syntax and join with regex `.*` (or `.+` if you want your `*` to mean "at least one character). This will avoid incorrect results when using `*`, `.`, `(`, `)` and all the other regex special characters.

Try something like:

```
public Pattern createPatternFromSearch(String query) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String part : query.split("\\*")) {
        if (part.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(Pattern.quote(part));
        }
        sb.append(".*");
    }
    return Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
}

// ...

// then you can use it like....
Matcher matcher = createPatternFromQuery("*DEF*mno*rst").matcher(str);
if (matcher.matches()) {
   // process the matching result
}
```

Note that by using [Matcher#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) (not `find`) and leaving the trailing `.*`, it will cater for your syntax that is anchored at the start only.

Comment: There are no `\*`sequences in this solution (other than literal ones, which won't be misinterpreted - that's not how [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) works.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `*` with `.*` and you have your regular expression.

```
String str = "*DEF*mno*rst";
String regex = str.replaceAll("*", ".*");
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work in the general case: it's not anchored at _only_ the start, and it doesn't handle any special regex characters (`*`, `?`, `.`, `|`, `<`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` `{`, `}`, etc)

Comment: I agree @Nick B. We might want to escape special regex characters which will make it a bit complicated.